# This webpage has a redirect loop - Devise , Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, devise

I got this error when i try to redirect the user into the requested path after he logs in.

Let's say when he clicks on a link of "My accounts settings" which is secured, he is redirected to the login page to authenticate, then back to the "My account settings" page if the authentication is a success.

By it creates a loop error, which is due to my understanding to the fact that he is being redirected form login to the page which needs login than again the page (because he is already athenticated)...

Now i tried to solve this problem by doing the following:

In `ApplicationController`

```
before_action :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  return unless request.get? 
  if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/new" &&
      request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&
      request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&
      request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
  end
end


def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session.delete(:previous_url)  || root_path
end

def logged_in?
  current_user ? true : false
end
```

In `PagesController`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show], :unless => :logged_in?
```

So that, after the successful authentication, we skip the :authenticate_user! to go directly to render the show view (instead of going into the login/redirect logic...)

Unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.

Do you see something that i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

**Try adding**

```
session["user_return_to"] = request.fullpath
```

to your store_location method after " !request.xhr?)"

**Replacing**

```
session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
```

Comment: But that means it will go to root_path, right ? I want to go to "My account settings" page which is not the root_path...

Comment: I edited what I meant -- I meant replace as in what you had there. My suggestion is the top snippet replacing yours on the bottom

Comment: Same problem ! Obviously, i had to add it also `after_sign_in_path_for`  by replacing the return line with `session["user_return_to"] || root_path`

Comment: Yea, with no :previous_url there. So you're saying that the problem is persisting?